# What are these two sticks on chart holders?

Tags: feature-identification, cockpit

Many different airplanes feature two small sticks on both sides of chart holders. These can be moved within a limited range. I've heard different versions about their use and haven't found any documentation regarding them.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You aren't going to find any documentation from the Learjet 45 AFM or PM.  They allow the pilot with paper charts to adjust the angle of the chart so the pilot can read it easier while flying.  There is no other purpose for those extra "small sticks"

Comment: All the versions I've heard, including my own, agree that it's to increase the angle of the chart so that it can be seen better. However, I've heard different versions regarding how to use them. Some say that the sticks tilt toward the pilot and the card rests on them, or that the sticks lower toward the yoke and the entire chart holder is tilted

Comment: I would imagine the bolt at the top of the chart holder is tight enough to keep the chart at any angle.

Comment: That's a theory and it makes sense; however, the other one could also be valid since it works and even allows writing on the chart holder without it coming off. I've seen this specific model in many planes like MD, CRJ, ATR... Experienced pilots I've asked haven't been able to confirm it definitively and even they have doubts.

Comment: @MiguelHernández You wouldn't have the chart holder tilt _and_ have legs prop the chart up, that would be redundant. It would make sense to have the holder tilt and the legs hold it up, forming a triangle. That's the same concept as the Boeing holder. Note too it tilts the light at the same time, avoiding the chart self-shadowing.